# Prove that for all integers $n\geq 2, n^3+1>n^2+n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am attempting this by induction.

Base case
$2^3+1 >2^2+2 \implies 8>6,$ which is true.

Now the induction step $(n+1)^3+1>(n+1)^2+(n+1),$ which simplifies to $n^3+3n^2+3n+2 > n^2+3n+2.$

I am not sure what to do, how do I involve the induction hypothesis? And are there approaches that I can take without using induction?

Comment: try to factor out (n+1) from both sides of the equality.

Comment: How can you simplify both sides without compromising the inequality? Keep in mind that $n \ge 2$ when adjusting terms.

Comment: Induction is not the fastest way.

Comment: The induction hypothesis tells you that $(n+1)^3 + 1 = n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 2 > 4n^2 + 4n + 1$.

Comment: @DavidL Ok so factoring I have $(n+1)(n^2+2n+1)+1 > (n+1)^2+(n+1) $

Comment: @AndréNicolas a direct proof would be faster? I see it now

Comment: You want to prove that $n^3-n^2\gt n-1$, that is, that $n^2(n-1)\gt n-1$. This is obvious if $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Why factor?  Just break it up into $(n^3 + 2n^2) + n^2 + 3n + 2 > n^2 + 3n + 2$.

Answer (score 3):

For $n\ge 2$:
$$n^3 - n^2 - n + 1 = (n-1)^2(n+1) \ge 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Easier to observe $$n^3+1\gt n^2+n$$ is equivalent to $$n^3-n^2-n+1\gt 0
$$ which is the same as as $$(n^2-1)(n-1)\gt 0$$
or $$(n-1)^2(n+1)\gt 0$$

Comment: Since we can easily prove the equivalent we have proven the original? Ok

Comment: @grayQuant You can work every step backwards, or just multiply the thing out.